# Why can't I use the blank identifier in the following Go code?

Tags: go

```
for _, arg := range flag.Args() {
    go func() {
        path.Walk(arg, dupes, walkerrs)
        walkend <- true
    }()
}
for _ := range flag.Args() {
    if !<-walkend {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

The second use of `_` gives this error: `no new variables on left side of :=`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this line:

`for _ = range flag.Args() {`

The error should disappear if you omit initialization for the blank identifier.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there's no point inferring type for the blank identifier, and it wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 7):

`:=` is a short variable declaration. `_` is not a real variable, so you can't declare it.

You should use `=` instead, when you don't have any new variables.

Answer (score 4):

An update for this question, as of Go 1.4 (current tip), you can use `for range flag.Args() { ... }` directly skipping the `_ =` part.